# Why is the value still 2 after printing? This occurs even when the address is changed to the area address

Tags: c++, pointers

I wanted to "return" a value using a void function with a pointer with only 2 values passed. But when I wanted to print out the value of area. It equals to 2, not 4. I tried changing the address of length++ to the address of area but still doesnt work

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    void yes(int* lol,int* lol2);
    
    using namespace std;
    
    
    int main()
    {
        static int length, width,area;
        int* p;
        length = 2;
        width = 2;
        p = &length;
    
        yes(&length, &width);
    
        cout << length << " " << *(p+1);
        cout << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    
    void yes(int* length, int* width)
    {
        int area;
        int* p=&area;
        area = *length * *width;
        length = length + 1;
        length = p;
    }
```

Comment: Also, I cant change the type of function type. Only void and not void*.

Comment: `length = length + 1; length = p;` - not sure what this is supposed to do, but it will only change the local variable. You don't want to change the pointer, but the value it's pointing to `*length = ...`

Comment: And keep an eye on ` *(p+1)`, it's undefined behaviour, `p` doesn't point to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
    length = length + 1;
    length = p;
```

with

```
    *length = *p;
```

or more simply get rid of `p` and change it to

```
    *length = area;
```

`length = p;` copies the pointer from `p` to `length`. `*length = *p;` copies what the pointer `p` is pointing at, to the place that `length` is pointing at. There's a difference between copying pointers and copying what the pointers are pointing at. Lots of beginner mistakes concerning pointers are caused by getting confused between the pointer and what the pointer is pointing at, these are two different things.

You don't need the second pointer `p`, so the simplest thing it to get rid of it and use `*length = area;`. That copies the value of `area` to the location that `length` is pointing at. Which is what you want (I think).

Comment: Yes, I want the value of area but I don't want to change the original value of length and also I wanted to change the address of Length+1 to the address of area not the value.

Comment: If you want to change the value of `area` in main, then you must pass a pointer to `area` into your function. It's impossible to change the value of `area` using a pointer to `length` because there is no valid way to get from the pointer to `length` to a pointer to `area`.

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```
length = length + 1;
length = p;
```

with

```
*length = *p;
```

and you are good to go